# breaking down any String

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

Hi guys I am busy with breaking / splitting Strings. 
However the String is not fixed so when the input changes the program still has to work with any  character input.

Till now I got this far but I got lost.

I have made an array of characters and set the size of the array equal to the lenght of any string that is will get as input. I made a for loop to loop through the characters of a string.

how do I insert my string now into the array because I know that my string is not yet in there? Then when its finally looping through the characters of my string is has to printout numbers and operands on different lines. So the ouput would look like in this case like this;

1

+

3

,

432

.

123

etc

I want to do this without using matchers,scanner, etc. I want to use basic Java techniques like you learn in the first 3 chapters of HeadfirstJava.

```
public class CharAtExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // This is the string we are going to break down
    String inputString = "1+3,432.123*4535-24.4";

    int stringLength = inputString.length();    

    char[] destArray = new char[stringLength];{

        for (int i=0; i<stringLength; i++);
    }
```

Comment: `how do I insert my string now into the array` Not sure what this means.  What do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: My output is in my post " So the ouput would look like in this case like this"

Comment: Are you asking us how to **parse** the string into **tokens**? If so, please do some research, since there are lots of articles out there for how to do parsing.

Comment: Well you don't show what produces your output, so how would we know what you want to do with the internal data?  I assume you mean you want each element in the array to hold one line of output.  You can't do that with a character array, because three characters ("432") can't fit in one array element.  You'll have to use a String array, or a two dimensional character array `char[][]`.

Comment: I want to do it with basic techniques andreas. Later this code will become a calculator.

Comment: As an aside, "basic technique" in Java, or any language, means one uses the API and doesn't try to make things difficult.  Good programmers don't reinvent the wheel.  I get what you are trying to do, but it's not normal to try to do stuff like this without using existing code in the API.

Comment: Thnx Mark im gonna look to that. However I thought with .getchars I could hold multiple elements.

Comment: If you mean `String.getChars()` then you'd either need a two dimensional array or you'd need to throw away the previous result to make room for a new one.

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier than you might think. 
 
First: to get an array with the chars of your string you just use the `toCharArray()` method that all strings have. 
 ex. `myString.toCharArray()` 
 
Second: When you see that a character is not a number, you want to move to the next line, print the character and then move to the next line again. 
 
The following code does exactly that :

```
public class JavaApplication255 {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputString = "1+3,432.123*4535-24.4";   

    char[] destArray = inputString.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < destArray.length ; i++){
        char c = destArray[i];

        if (isBreakCharacter(c)){
            System.out.println("\n" + c);
        } else {
            System.out.print(c);
        }

    }
}

public static boolean isBreakCharacter(char c){
    return c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '-' || c == '.' || c == ',' ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bloodeye this is very easy to follow as a beginner! I didnt know it was that "easy".

Comment: I have one last question why does the reference variable destArray needs to be destArray[i] ? why it needs the index from the loop between []?

Comment: An array has a lot of items in it. To get an item, you need to know where it is. For example to get the first item from an array, you would write myArray[0] (because arrays start counting at 0). So on the first line you use destArray[i] to get the char at position i (which, remember, changes on each iteration of the loop. It starts at 0 , then 1, then 2 etc. and stops at the last char of the array).  Not sure if i understanded correctly your question though. So If i didn't, please ellaborate more and i'll try to help.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know! Thank you! I understand the code completely now.

Comment: Glad to hear that ! have fun programming and have a nice day !(or night .-.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Character.isDigit(char)` to distinguish numeric and not numeric chars as actually this is the single criteria to group multiple chars in a same line.
It would give :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputString = "1+3,432.123*4535-24.4";
    String currentSequence = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {

        char currentChar = inputString.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(currentChar)) {
            currentSequence += currentChar;
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(currentSequence);
        System.out.println(currentChar);
        currentSequence = "";
    }

    // print the current sequence that is a number if not printed yet
    if (!currentSequence.equals("")) {
         System.out.println(currentSequence);
    }

}
```

`Character.isDigit()` relies on unicode category.
You could code it yourself such as :

```
if (Character.getType(currentChar) == Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER) {...}
```

Or you could code it still at a lower level by checking that the `int` value of the `char` is included in the range of [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) decimal values for numbers:

```
if(currentChar >= 48 && currentChar <= 57 ) {
```

It outputs what you want :

> 1
>
> +
>
> 3
>
> ,
>
> 432
>
> .
>
> 123
>
> *
>
> 4535
>
> -
>
> 24
>
> .
>
> 4

Comment: if I adjust the string it does not print out the last charachter. e.g. 1+1+1+1+1 outputs 1+1+1+1+

Comment: works like a charm! This is my 2nd week of intensive Java programming I never could come up with this!

Comment: Thank you I will!

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] charArray = inputString.toCharArray();
```

Comment: then I make a second array?

Comment: @Amirates Why would you make a second `char[]`?

Comment: Ow wait  im making an object here and not a second array?

Comment: You are making a char array out of a string. Same length same values.

Comment: I am a beginner so this answer without any explanation was quite hard. But I understand now that the String class has a .toCharArray method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution where we go character by character and either add to an existing string which will be our numbers or it adds the string to the array, clears the current number and then adds the special characters. Finally we loop through the array as many times as we find a number or non-number character. I used the ASCII table to identify a character as a digit, the table will come in handy throughout your programming career. Lastly I changed the array to a String array because a character can't hold a number like "432", only '4' or '3' or '2'.

```
String inputString = "1+3,432.123*4535-24.4";

int stringLength = inputString.length();    

String[] destArray = new String[stringLength];
int destArrayCount = 0;
String currentString = "";
for (int i=0; i<stringLength; i++)
{
    //check it's ascii value if its between 0 (48) and 9 (57)
    if(inputString.charAt(i) >= 48 && inputString.charAt(i) <= 57 )
    {
        currentString += inputString.charAt(i);
    }
    else
    {
        destArray[destArrayCount++] = currentString;
        currentString = "";
        //we know we don't have a number at i so its a non-number character, add it
        destArray[destArrayCount++] = "" + inputString.charAt(i);
    }
}
//add the last remaining number
destArray[destArrayCount++] = currentString;

for(int i = 0; i < destArrayCount; i++)
{
    System.out.println("(" + i + "): " + destArray[i]);
}
```

**IMPORTANT** - This algorithm will fail if a certain type of String is used. Can you find a String where this algorithm fails? What can you do to to ensure the count is always correct and not sometimes 1 greater than the actual count?

Comment: General comment: not here that Raz switches your char array for a String array. `String[] destArray = new String[stringLength];`  "432" is a string (three characters) and needs a string to hold it, not a char.